# How can I assign scores to a list of datapoints and then output values > 2 standard deviations from the mean in python?

Tags: python, arrays, statistics

I wrote a script that reads through a text file with rows of data. Example of a line of data:

```
10      1100    1101    G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       A/G     G       G       G       A/G     G       G       A/G     A/G     G       G       A/G     G       A/G     G       G       G       G       G       .       G       A/G     A/G     G       G       A/G     G       G       G       A/G     G       A       A/G     A/G     A/G     G       G       A/G     G       G       G       A/G     .       G       A       A/G     A       .       A       A       A       G       G       G       A       G       A/G     A/G     A/G     A       G       A/G     A       A       A       A       A       A       A/G     A
```

My script calculates a frequency score for each row of data as a percentage based on the relative number of different letters. Currently my script outputs a subset of the row and the percentage score if the percentage score is >0.75. 
However I would like to make the script do something more sophisticated but I do not know how. 
1) For each row of data I would like the script to save the 1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th column of data in an array and also add the percentage score as an additional value. 
2) Then once the script has read through all rows in the text file I would like it to output all the rows with percentage scores >2 standard deviations above the mean percentage score.

Below find my current script.

(one small but non-essential additional thing, currently I print each relevant row twice because if a percentage score that is >0.75 for one letter will also always be >0.75 for another letter. To get around this I just have to get the script to continue onto the next row of data once it has printed out once, but I always get confused if I should use break, continue or something else to get the script to move on to the next line without ending the entire script.)

```
inputfile = open('datafile.txt', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')



#windowstart = 0
for line in inputfile:

    line = line.rstrip() 
    fields = line.split("\t")
    chrom = fields[0]
    pos = str(fields[1])
    allele_one = str(fields[3])
    allele_two = str(fields[4])

#which columns belong to which population   
    PopulationA = fields[3:26]
    PopulationB = fields[26:36]

#sample size of each population 
    PopulationA_popsize = 46
    PopulationB_popsize = 20


#Now count the total number of alleles in each population (Homozygous alleles counted twice, heterozygotes just once)   

#count C allele
    C_count_PopulationA = (2*PopulationA.count("C")) + PopulationA.count("C/T") + PopulationA.count("A/C") + PopulationA.count("C/G")
    percentage_C_PopulationA = float(C_count_PopulationA)/46

#count A allele

    A_count_PopulationA = (2*PopulationA.count("A")) + PopulationA.count("A/T") + PopulationA.count("A/C") + PopulationA.count("A/G")
    percentage_A_PopulationA = float(A_count_PopulationA)/46

#count T allele

    T_count_PopulationA = (2*PopulationA.count("T")) + PopulationA.count("C/T") + PopulationA.count("A/T") + PopulationA.count("G/T")
    percentage_T_PopulationA = float(T_count_PopulationA)/46

#count G allele

    G_count_PopulationA = (2*PopulationA.count("G")) + PopulationA.count("G/T") + PopulationA.count("A/G") + PopulationA.count("C/G")
    percentage_G_PopulationA = float(G_count_PopulationA)/46

#count missing data 
    null_count_PopulationA = (2*PopulationA.count("."))
    percentage_null_PopulationA = float(null_count_PopulationA)/46

#repeat for population B

    C_count_PopulationB = (2*PopulationB.count("C")) + PopulationB.count("C/T") + PopulationB.count("A/C") + PopulationB.count("C/G")
    percentage_C_PopulationB = float(C_count_PopulationB)/20

    A_count_PopulationB = (2*PopulationB.count("A")) + PopulationB.count("A/T") + PopulationB.count("A/C") + PopulationB.count("A/G")
    percentage_A_PopulationB = float(A_count_PopulationB)/20

    T_count_PopulationB = (2*PopulationB.count("T")) + PopulationB.count("C/T") + PopulationB.count("A/T") + PopulationB.count("G/T")
    percentage_T_PopulationB = float(T_count_PopulationB)/20

    G_count_PopulationB = (2*PopulationB.count("G")) + PopulationB.count("G/T") + PopulationB.count("A/G") + PopulationB.count("C/G")
    percentage_G_PopulationB = float(G_count_PopulationB)/20

    null_count_PopulationB = (2*PopulationB.count("."))
    percentage_null_PopulationB = float(null_count_PopulationB)/20



#If missing data less than 10% in both populations  
    if percentage_null_PopulationA < 0.1:
        if percentage_null_PopulationB < 0.1:
#calculate frequency difference between populations for each allele         
            Frequency_diff_C_PopulationA_PopulationB = float(abs(percentage_C_PopulationA - percentage_C_PopulationB))
            Frequency_diff_A_PopulationA_PopulationB = float(abs(percentage_A_PopulationA - percentage_A_PopulationB))
            Frequency_diff_T_PopulationA_PopulationB = float(abs(percentage_T_PopulationA - percentage_T_PopulationB))
            Frequency_diff_G_PopulationA_PopulationB = float(abs(percentage_G_PopulationA - percentage_G_PopulationB))
#if the frequency difference between alleles is greater than 0.75, print part of the row            
            if Frequency_diff_C_PopulationA_PopulationB >= 0.75:

                print >> output, str(chrom) + "\t" + str(pos) + "\t" + str(allele_one) + "\t" + str(allele_two)

            if Frequency_diff_A_PopulationA_PopulationB >= 0.75:

                print >> output, str(chrom) + "\t" + str(pos) + "\t" + str(allele_one) + "\t" + str(allele_two)

            if Frequency_diff_T_PopulationA_PopulationB >= 0.75:

                print >> output, str(chrom) + "\t" + str(pos) + "\t" + str(allele_one) + "\t" + str(allele_two)

            if Frequency_diff_G_PopulationA_PopulationB >= 0.75:

                print >> output, str(chrom) + "\t" + str(pos) + "\t" + str(allele_one) + "\t" + str(allele_two)
```

I am looking to find the allele frequency difference between the populations for each row. So for example if we imagine there are 10 individuals in population A (first 10 columns of nucleotides) and 10 individuals in population B (final 10 columns of nucleotides then in the example row of data below we see that population A has 10 G nucleotides. Population B has 3 G nucleotides and 7 A nucleotides. So the frequency difference between the 2 populations is 70%.

```
10      20    21    G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G      G       G       G       A       A       A       A      A       A       A
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Ok noted. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you talk of means and standard deviations for lots of data, you should start using any of the numerical libraries. Consider using numpy, or even pandas (for readability) here. I'll be using them in this example, together with the [Counter object from the collections module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Read up on both to see how they work, but I'll explain a bit throughout the code as well.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter    

nucleotid_bases = ('C', 'A', 'T', 'G', '.')
results = []
checksum = []
with open('datafile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()  # splits by consecutive whitespace, empty records will be purged
        chrom, pos = [int(fields[x]) for x in (0,1)]
        results.append([chrom,pos])  # start by building the current record
        allele1, allele2 = [fields[i] for i in (3,4)]
        checksum.append([allele1, allele2])  # you wanted to keep these, most likely for debugging purposes?
        popA = fields[3:26]  # population size: 2*23
        popB = fields[26:36]  # population size: 2*10
        for population in (popA, popB):
            summary = Counter(population) # traverses the line only once - much more efficient!
            base_counts = [ sum(summary[k] for k in summary.keys() if base in k) for base in nucleotid_bases]
            for index, base_name in enumerate(nucleotid_bases):
                # Double the count when there is an exact match, e.g. "A/A" -> "A"
                # An 'in' match can match an item anywhere in the string: 'A' in 'A/C' evaluates to True
                base_counts[index] += summary[base_name]    
            results[-1].extend(base_counts)  # append to the current record
results = np.array(results, dtype=np.float)  # shape is now (x, 12) with x the amount of lines read
results[:, 2:7] /= 46
results[:, 7:] /= 20
```

At this point, the layout of the `results` is two columns filled with the `chrom` (`results[:,0]`) and `pos` (`results[:,1]`) labels from the text file,
then 5 columns of population A, where the first of those 5 contains the relative frequency of the 'C' base, next
 column of the 'A' base and so on (see `nucleotid_bases` for the order). Then, the last 5 columns are similar, but they are for population B:

```
chrom, pos, freqC_in_A,..., freqG_in_A, freq_dot_in_A freqC_in_B, ..., freqG_in_B, freq_dot_in_B
```

If you want to ignore records (rows) in this table where either of the unknowns-frequencies (columns 6 and 11) are above a threshold, you would do:

```
threshold = .1 # arbitrary: 10%
to_consider = np.logical_and(results[:,6] < threshold, results[:,11] < threshold)
table = results[to_consider][:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]]
```

Now you can compute the table of frequency differences with:

```
freq_diffs  = np.abs(table[:,2:6] - table[:,-4:])  # 4 columns, n rows

mean_freq_diff = freq_diffs.mean(axis=0) # holds 4 numbers, these are the means over all the rows
std_freq_diff = freq_diffs.std(axis=0) # similar: std over all the rows

condition = freq_diffs > (mean_freq_diff + 2*std_freq_diff)
```

Now you'll want to check if the `condition` was valid for any elements of the row, so e.g. if
the frequency difference for 'C' between popA and popB was .8 and the
(mean+2*std) was .7, then it will return True. But it will also return True
for the same row if this condition was fulfilled for any of the other
nucleotids. To check if the condition was True for any of the nucleotid frequency differences, do this:

```
specials = np.any(condition, axis=1)  
print(table[specials, :2])
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. I will look through this today and let you know if it works.

Comment: This looks very good and much more efficient. However I was unclear about the output, which is close to what I am after but not exactly. I do not want to output the results that are >2 standard deviations for the C,T,A,G nucleotides separately, but rather to combine all nucleotides for calculating the mean frequency, then outputting all cases that are >2std above for this combined set. Does that make sense? Maybe you already do this but I misunderstood.

Comment: AMaybe I am misunderstanding but as I follow your code it givesthe mean for the frequency of nucleotide C in population A. However I am interested in is the frequency DIFFERENCE in nucleotides between population A and B. For each row there will only be 2 nucleotides, so my blunt force way of calculating the frequency for each nucleotide separately is overkill. For each row I need the freq difference (value between 0 and 1) between the nucleotides in PopA and PopB, then to find the mean frequency difference. Finally to print those results where the freqdifference is >2std above the mean.

Comment: @user964689, I believe I understand you better now and have updated the answer to include more what you are looking for (I think). If it's not what you want, perhaps you can give an example with made-up numbers for the frequencies for about 3 lines of data and include that in your original post?

Comment: Thanks I will check through it and give an example if necessary

Comment: How would you modify it to exclude rows where a certain percentage of sites in either population A or B. So these rows are basically treated like they dont exist in the data file. (would be good to count how many such sites exist for interest)

Comment: @user964689 Do you want that "certain percentage" to be the same for both the A frequencies and B frequencies? Could you give a numeric example in terms of that tabular layout, so with `[fC_in_A, fA_in_A, fT_in_A, fG_in_A, funknown_in_A, fC_in_B, fA_in_B, fT_in_B, fG_in_B, funknown_in_B]`?

Comment: I added a simplified example at the end of my question. Also I get an error: for index, base_name in nucleotid_bases: 
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. Is there an easier place to discuss here that doesnt fill up the comments like this? Thanks

Comment: @user964689 Sure, join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68904/stackoverflow-q27947419).

Comment: I sent a couple of short questions to the chat, if it is still active for you

Comment: Added a few other questions, maybe easiest to discuss when you are around. If you do have time let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey, an error I am having trouble debugging - posted in chat if you have time to take a look. Many thanks.

Comment: I have another debugging question in chat. Thanks